# Get tab title onCreate tab

Tags: android, tabs

I need to get the tab title when I first open my app. I can do it when the user changes the tab and save it in shared pref by using onTabSelected but if the user does not change the tab, I don't know how to access the title. Im using this:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(
        new ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(myViewPager) {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabSelected(tab);
                String dataTab = tab.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCIAS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("DATA", dataTab);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that after setting up the `TabLayout` by using

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getText()
```

Comment: I understand but my "default" tab isnt the index 0, is the "last" added to the tablayout. Im trying this: 'String dataTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getTabCount()).getText().toString();' but I get that tablayout is a null object.

Comment: You should try `tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getTabCount() - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the title of the selected tab.

```
int selectedTabIndex = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(selectedTabIndex);
String tabTitle = tab.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next method for get tab title:

```
private String getTabText(Integer tabPosition){
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(tabPosition);
        return tab.getText().toString();
}
```